# Want to change the color of every div except the one dblclicked?

Tags: jquery

I already have this code for the single click functions, but need to add the function of changing the colour of every div except the one that is dbl-clicked? Hope that someone can help me.

```
<body>

  <h2>Traversering og elementskapelse</h2>
  <div>
    <label>Antall div'er å generere:
            <input id="nmbrSquare" type="number" value="5">
        </label>
    <input id="addSquareBtn" type="button" value="Generér">
  </div>
  <div id="boxes"></div>


  <script>

    function generateDivs(amount) {
      container.empty();
      for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        var div = $('<div>');
        div.addClass('box');
        container.append(div);
      }
    }

    var container = $('#boxes');

    $("#addSquareBtn").click(function() {
      var nmbrSquare = $("#nmbrSquare").val();
      generateDivs(nmbrSquare)
    });

    generateDivs(1);

    $(function() {  
        $(document).on('click','#boxes',function(){
            $(event.target).css('background-color', 'plum');
            $(event.target).prev().css('background-color', 'plum');
            $(event.target).next().css('background-color', 'plum');
        });
    });  

  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: What `<div>`'s ... there is no html shown. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Change `'click'` to `'dblclick'`. If that doesn't cover exactly what you need, please edit your question to include the HTML

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have edited and added the HTML now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `click` to `dblclick` like below:-

***Example-***

```js
$(function() {  
    $(document).on('dblclick','#boxes',function(){
        $('div').not(this).css('background-color', 'plum');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Hi</div><br>
<div>Hello</div><br>
<div id="boxes">Click Me!</div><br>

<div>Hey</div><br>
```